# Format date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

How can I parse a date like '2012-08-22 11:55:38

to '8 of August'

I tried with formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM");

But I'm getting an 'Unparseable date' exception.

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Try to rephrase your question, I don't think anyone could make any sense of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *parse* from a string to a `Date`. You can then *format* from a `Date` to a string using a different pattern. Currently, given the code you've shown us, it looks like you're trying to parse the value "2012-08-22 11:55:38" with a `SimpleDateFormat` *expecting* the pattern "d MMM", which it clearly doesn't comply to. You should have something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                                    Locale.US);
// TODO: Set the time zone appropriately
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM", targetLocale);
// TODO: Set the time zone appropriately
String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Note that if you're doing any significant amount of date/time work in Java, you should look into [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which is a much better date/time API.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (if I understand what you are asking):

```
String s = "2012-08-22 11:55:38";
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dt = fmt.parse(s);
DateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("d 'of' MMMM", Locale.US);
System.out.println(output.format(dt)); //prints 22 of August
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having problem while parsing the date from the input string.

"2012-08-22 11:55:38" is in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format, which you should use to first parse the date from the input string.

Then once you have a `Date` object, you can format the date in the required format.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correct, you try to parse the first string to a date and then format the resulted date to the seconds string. If this is true then see the code below:

```
SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'of' MMMM");
try {
  java.util.Date date = f1.parse("2012-08-22 11:55:38");
  System.out.println(f2.format(date));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```